# Date picker format from default to any format

Tags: html, angular

I tried to format the date to yyyy-MM-dd but it is not working. I am using Angular

[Date](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kZ87I.png)

```
<input type="date" class="form-control" onfocus="(this.type='date')"
  placeholder="Date of Birth" formControlName="dob"
  min="{{ minDate | date: 'yyyy-MM-dd'}}"
  max="{{ maxDate | date: 'yyyy-MM-dd'}}"
  [ngModel]="dob | date:'yyyy-MM-dd'"
  (ngModelChange)="dob = $event"
>
```

Comment: create a hidden text input field and reformat the date upon submitting the form, putting it in the hidden text field

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not possible to change the format of the `<input type="date">`.

The explanation is here: [Is there any way to change input type="date" format?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7372038/is-there-any-way-to-change-input-type-date-format)

You have to use a custom datepicker like [Angular Material Datepicker](https://material.angular.io/components/datepicker/overview) or [NgBootstrap Datepicker](https://ng-bootstrap.github.io/#/components/datepicker/api) or other